# Suppress warning while compiling using g++

Tags: gcc, c++17, g++, gcc-warning

When compiling a project using g++

```
g++  -fPIC -O -std=c++17 -rdynamic -D_REENTRANT -I"All Include directories" -L"Library paths" <All the o files>  -l"boost_system" -l"served" -ldl  -lpthread -o "MyApp"
```

getting an error without creating the binary,

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.57.0, needed by Support/RESTLibs/served/lib_8.5_R/libserved.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
Support/RESTLibs/served/lib_8.5_R/libserved.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
Support/RESTLibs/served/lib_8.5_R/libserved.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

I have tried adding `-w` still the error is there.

but the same is working fine (binary is created) in Debug build with a warning.

```
g++  -fPIC -g -std=c++17 -rdynamic -D_REENTRANT -I"All Include directories" -L"Library paths" <All the o files>  -l"boost_system" -l"served" -ldl  -lpthread -o "MyApp"
```

warning is :

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.57.0, needed by Support/RESTLibs/served/lib_8.5_R/libserved.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Comment: Instead of trying to suppress the warning, which is likely valid, perhaps you should figure out how to make `libboost_system.so.1.57.0` available.